# Make file variable is empty

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here I am trying to build one target from the makefile which looks like this.

```
VER := 13.1-9.6
V1 = $(word 1,$(subst -, ,$(VER)))
V2 = $(word 2,$(subst -, ,$(VER)))
hello:
    cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_$(V1).txt;
    cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_$(V2).txt;
```

here, just want to split the "13.1-9.6" to "13.1" and "9.6"
and finally, create the 2 files.

but getting the following output

```
cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_.txt;
cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_.txt;
```

what is the issue here, why are the variables are empty?

I am on Freebsd 11.4-RELEASE

the output of `gmake -v`

```
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for amd64-portbld-freebsd11.3
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Clearly whatever code you're _actually_ running is not the code you showed us.  First, the code here is missing closing parens in both the V1 and V2 variable assignments.  Second, if I fix that then this makefile works fine just as you hoped it would. So, whatever is wrong in your environment it's something you haven't told us about.

Comment: ya, make didn't give the error, but ya added the closing ), 
still the output is the same. :(

Comment: If make didn't give an error on the original makefile, then something is seriously wrong.  Are you sure you're using GNU make?  What does `make --version` print?

Comment: no, `make --version` it does not print anything. 
i am new to make stuff. 
here i am using FreeBSD 11.4, I think, with gmake

Comment: Please edit your question and show the exact command line you ran and the exact output you got (cut and paste).

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this so I have no idea what is going on.  Maybe the FreeBSD folks applied some local patch to GNU make that modifies its behavior, or else you're doing something different in your setup.

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

~$ cat Makefile
VER := 13.1-9.6
V1 = $(word 1,$(subst -, ,$(VER)))
V2 = $(word 2,$(subst -, ,$(VER)))
hello:
        : cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_$(V1).txt;
        : cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_$(V2).txt;

~$ make
: cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_13.1.txt;
: cp ./path/file.txt ./path/file_9.6.txt;
```